# Why mov/cmp instead of cmp with two memory operands?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, instructions, mov

I came through the following statement while going through a binary search program code

```
l1: mov si,low_
    cmp si,high_
```

Why do we need to store low_ in si and then compare with high_ ?
Can't we directly write cmp low_,high_

Comment: Only up to one memory operand is supported by most x86 instructions.

Comment: Did you try it?  Your assembler would have told you "too many memory operands".

Comment: Try it first, then ask here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write `cmp low_, high_`.

For such questions, always refer to the official instruction description, e.g. at https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp.  Note that `cmp` has forms `cmp r/m16, r16`, for which the first operand can be either register or memory, and the second must be a register; as well as `cmp r16, r/m16` which is the reverse.  But there is nothing like `cmp r/m16, r/m16` or `cmp m16, m16`.  So `cmp low_, high_` would be attempting to assemble an instruction which does not exist, and your assembler will reject it.

This is the case for most x86 arithmetic instructions: one of the operands may be a memory reference, but not both.  To operate on two values from memory, you must load one of them into a register first, as this code does.